# Kill multiple connections at a time

Tags: mysql, root, activejdbc, javalite, connection-pool

I am using root as username.

My program will refresh every 5 seconds.
What it does is, it query from mysql table and display the data.

Problem is, every after 5 seconds, the connection on mysql will append, reason that it will give an error of "TOO MUCH CONNECTIONS" when it reach the limit.

Is it possible to kill the previous connection since it is unused already?

Here is my code on opening a connection.

```
connectionPool = connectionPool.getConnectionPool("root", "*****", "");
```

Comment: Close all connections ? http://jpos.org/doc/javadoc/org/jpos/tpl/ConnectionPool.html

Comment: Use connection pooling and increase max_connection variable according to your 
 MySQL server capacity

Comment: @SudiptaMondal
Not all connections. previous connections only. Since ths program will continue to run

Comment: @SumeshTG what about when it hits the new limit? You are just ignoring the real problem.

Comment: Should set timeout for every connections @tanaydin

Comment: @SumeshTG which one is correct :) max_connection or timeout? you are suggesting a different thing to defense first suggestion... timeout for connection is for "connection" not for "idle connections", it gets fired if the connection is not established given time.

Comment: @tanaydin I solved this situation by profiling mysql server(set max_con,increase cache .. etc) and kill all idle connection by executing query in another thread using processing id dynamically. Some connection become idle after timeout.

Comment: @SumeshTG this is not a solution, this is cover. It is ridiculous to close "idle" connections with another one. What should you do if this "disconnector" can't connect because of connection limit? You have to free pool instance or close connection after your execution is over, then you don't need another thread for "disconnecting" previous connections.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior if you are using a connection pool. When your job is over be sure that you free the connection instance, or close all pool connections when your code execution is done.

Comment: So there is no way to close the previous connection? since it will refresh every 5s, it will open another connection while the previous connection is not usable anymore.

Comment: you have to close your own connection, you shouldn't leave it for next execution.

Comment: add a finally and close the used connection @AyukNayr

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with a connection, you need to close it. this will return a connection back to the pool.